# Vector of pointers segfaulting on call to size() and upon creation of an iterator

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, sfml

I have a class which contains a vector of pointers to a class. In most of its member functions, I can access and modify the vector just fine. However, in one function even calling .size() or getting an iterator causes a segfault in my program.

Here is the class with the vector of pointers to a class:

```
class floor
{
public:
  floor(string imageFile, string a_walkwayFile, string waypointFile, int a_id, sf::Vector2i a_pos);
  ~floor();

  int getId() { return id; };
  void update(sf::RenderWindow* App);
  sf::Sprite* getSprite() { return sprite; };
  vector<int> parseCSVLine(string line);
  void loadWalkways();
  void convertToView(sf::RenderWindow* App, sf::View* view);
  bool pointInWalkway(sf::Vector2f pt);

private:
  vector<sf::RectangleShape*> walkWays;
  sf::Sprite* sprite;
  int id;
  float scale;
  string walkwayFile;
};
```

Here is a snippet whee objects are added to the vector:

```
walkWays.push_back(new sf::RectangleShape());
walkWays[walkWays.size() - 1]->setPosition(sf::Vector2f(parsedLine[0], parsedLine[1]));
walkWays[walkWays.size() - 1]->setSize(sf::Vector2f(parsedLine[2] - parsedLine[0], parsedLine[3] - parsedLine[1]));
walkWays[walkWays.size() - 1]->setFillColor(sf::Color(0,0,255,25));
walkWays[walkWays.size() - 1]->setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Blue);
walkWays[walkWays.size() - 1]->setOutlineThickness(3);
```

Here is a snippet of code which accesses the vector just fine always:

```
void floor::update(sf::RenderWindow* App)
{
  App->draw(*sprite);

  for(int i = 0; i < walkWays.size(); ++i)
    App->draw(*walkWays[i]);
}
```

Now here is the function where every call or reference to the function results in a segfault:

```
bool floor::pointInWalkway(sf::Vector2f pt)
{
  cout << walkWays.size() << endl; // this segfaults

  if(walkWays.size() != 0) // this segfaults
    for(vector<sf::RectangleShape*>::iterator it = walkWays.begin(); it != walkWays.end(); ++it) // this segfaults too!
      if((*it)->getGlobalBounds().contains(pt.x, pt.y))
        return true;
  return false;
}
```

Any pointers as to how I would fix this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you tried using gdb? or any sort of debugger on the program?

Comment: I've used the code::blocks debugger, which is why I know where it crashes. Also, the faulty function is called AFTER all of the objects are added to the vector, if that helps.

Comment: could you post all of your code to maybe paste bin? at least relating to the object, i cant seem to find a problem with your current code.

Comment: Here you go, thank you for looking: http://pastebin.com/aDpAz0y5

Comment: is the commented out section the section that is not working?

Comment: No, I just redid that section to see if the way I was declaring the sf::RectangleShape was the problem (it wasn't).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30233/discussion-between-need4sleep-and-lfnunley)

Answer (score 0):

Your file loop reads one to many times, try using a loop with this structure:

```
    string line;
    getline(file, line);    
    while(file)
    {
          if(parsedLine.size() == 4)
          {
            walkWays.push_back(new sf::RectangleShape());
            walkWays[walkWays.size() - 1]->setPosition(sf::Vector2f(parsedLine[0], parsedLine[1]));
            walkWays[walkWays.size() - 1]->setSize(sf::Vector2f(parsedLine[2] - parsedLine[0], parsedLine[3] - parsedLine[1]));
            walkWays[walkWays.size() - 1]->setFillColor(sf::Color(0,0,255,25)); 
            walkWays[walkWays.size() - 1]->setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Blue);
            walkWays[walkWays.size() - 1]->setOutlineThickness(3);
            /*sf::RectangleShape* rect = new sf::RectangleShape();
            rect->setPosition(sf::Vector2f(parsedLine[0], parsedLine[1]));
            rect->setSize(sf::Vector2f((float)parsedLine[2] - parsedLine[0], (float)parsedLine[3] - parsedLine[1]));
            rect->setFillColor(sf::Color(0,0,0,0));
            //rect->setOrigin(sf::Vector2f(parsedLine[0], parsedLine[2]));
            //cout << parsedLine[0] << ", " << parsedLine[1] << endl;
            rect->setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Blue);
            rect->setOutlineThickness(3);
            walkWays.push_back(rect);*/
          } 
          getline(file, line);
    }
```

this prevents your file from reading one to many times and will stop correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I followed it, but sadly, this did not fix my issue.

Comment: This is called before the drawing of the window and before the update function

Comment: could you send me main.cpp please :)

Comment: My main.cpp is only 60 lines or so, it wouldn't help you at all. Here is a link to a zip file with all of the files in it: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45353822/Firedrill%20Sim.zip

Comment: in the file you sent me you didnt make use of the loop I showed above, are you sure you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I'm positive. I don't know why it's not that way in the file, sorry.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30270/discussion-between-lfnunley-and-need4sleep)

Comment: @lfununly I'm currently on a school system that blocks stack chat, Ill download the files and give it another look however.